# How to get the asyncio.Cancelled error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I've tried capture the `asyncio.CancelledError` inside a `except` but the message are always empty

reading the python documentation about `CancelledError` it says to be careful to not suppress the error with a generic exception:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError

So i did

```py
try:
    my_method() # inside this method the asyncio.gather() is used
except CustomException as error:
    print(error)
except asyncio.CancelledError as error:
    print(f"operation canceled: {error}")
    # print(error.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2]) # didn't work as well
except Exception as error:
    print(f"Generic error: {error}")
```

the `try/except` block work as expected, how can i capture this message and what is the cause of it? the message showed on the exception is `operation canceled:`

Comment: You must first place the asyncio.Cancelled exception, followed by other exceptions that you want to capture. (follow the pattern specified by the link you shared). You can display the message with: str(error).

Comment: Could you please provide a small runnable example and specify the behavior you would like to obtain, along with the behavior you actually got? ("Didn't work as well" is a bit vague.)